# Python GUI tkinter Scientific Calculator

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, calculator

"Why the *sin* is not working it is giving me a syntax error? 
I am coding a scientific calculator in python 3.6

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from math import*

class Calculator:
    calc_value = 0.0
    div_trigger = False
    mult_trigger = False
    add_trigger = False
    sub_trigger = False
    asin_trigger = False


    def button_press(self, value):
        entry_val = self.number_entry.get()
        entry_val += value
        self.number_entry.delete(0, "end")
        self.number_entry.insert(0, entry_val)


    def isfloat(self, str_val):
        try:
            float(str_val)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False


    def math_button_press(self, value):
        if self.isfloat(str(self.number_entry.get())):
            self.add_trigger = False
            self.sub_trigger = False
            self.mult_trigger = False
            self.div_trigger = False
            self.asin_trigger = False
            self.calc_value = float(self.entry_value.get())
            if value == "/":
                print("/ Pressed")
                self.div_trigger = True
            elif value == "*":
                print("* Pressed")
                self.mult_trigger = True
            elif value == "+":
                print("+ Pressed")
                self.add_trigger = True
            elif value == "sin":
                print("sin Pressed")
                self.asin_trigger = True 
            else:
                print("- Pressed")
                self.sub_trigger = True
            self.number_entry.delete(0, "end")


    def equal_button_press(self):  
        if self.add_trigger or self.sub_trigger or self.mult_trigger or self.div_trigger or self.asin_trigger:

            if self.add_trigger:
                solution = self.calc_value + float(self.entry_value.get())
            elif self.sub_trigger:
                solution = self.calc_value - float(self.entry_value.get())
            elif self.mult_trigger:
                solution = self.calc_value * float(self.entry_value.get())
            elif self.asin_trigger:
                solution = self.calc_value sin float(self.entry_value.get())
            else:
                solution = self.calc_value / float(self.entry_value.get())

            print(self.calc_value, " ", float(self.entry_value.get()),
                                            " ", solution)

            #
            self.number_entry.delete(0, "end")

            self.number_entry.insert(0, solution)


    def __init__(self, root):
        self.entry_value = StringVar(root, value="")
        root.title("Calculator")
        root.geometry("860x440")
        root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        style = ttk.Style()
        style.configure("TButton",
                        font="Serif 15",
                        padding=10)

        style.configure("TEntry",
                        font="Serif 18",
                        padding=10)

        # Create the text entry box
        self.number_entry = ttk.Entry(root,
                        textvariable=self.entry_value, width=50)
        self.number_entry.grid(row=0, columnspan=4)

        # ----- 1st Row -----

        self.button7 = ttk.Button(root, text="7", command=lambda: self.button_press('7')).grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.button8 = ttk.Button(root, text="8", command=lambda: self.button_press('8')).grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.button9 = ttk.Button(root, text="9", command=lambda: self.button_press('9')).grid(row=1, column=2)

        self.button_div = ttk.Button(root, text="/", command=lambda: self.math_button_press('/')).grid(row=1, column=3)

        # ----- 2nd Row -----

        self.button4 = ttk.Button(root, text="4", command=lambda: self.button_press('4')).grid(row=2, column=0)

        self.button5 = ttk.Button(root, text="5", command=lambda: self.button_press('5')).grid(row=2, column=1)

        self.button6 = ttk.Button(root, text="6", command=lambda: self.button_press('6')).grid(row=2, column=2)

        self.button_mult = ttk.Button(root, text="*", command=lambda: self.math_button_press('*')).grid(row=2, column=3)

        # ----- 3rd Row -----

        self.button1 = ttk.Button(root, text="1", command=lambda: self.button_press('1')).grid(row=3, column=0)

        self.button2 = ttk.Button(root, text="2", command=lambda: self.button_press('2')).grid(row=3, column=1)

        self.button3 = ttk.Button(root, text="3", command=lambda: self.button_press('3')).grid(row=3, column=2)

        self.button_add = ttk.Button(root, text="+", command=lambda: self.math_button_press('+')).grid(row=3, column=3)

        # ----- 4th Row -----

        self.button_clear = ttk.Button(root, text="AC", command=lambda: self.button_press('AC')).grid(row=4, column=0)

        self.button0 = ttk.Button(root, text="0", command=lambda: self.button_press('0')).grid(row=4, column=1)

        self.button_equal = ttk.Button(root, text="=", command=lambda: self.equal_button_press()).grid(row=4, column=2)

        self.button_sub = ttk.Button(root, text="-", command=lambda: self.math_button_press('-')).grid(row=4, column=3)

        #------- 5th Row -------
        self.button_asin = ttk.Button(root, text="sin", command=lambda: self.math_button_press('sin')).grid(row=5, column=0)

root = Tk()

calc = Calculator(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Well, what did you expect `self.calc_value sin float(self.entry_value.get())` to do? `sin` is not an operator _and_ it takes a single parameter (not two).

Comment: In future, please try to condense your code to a [mcve] that focuses on your problem. (And please try to format code neatly, without huge slabs of pointless blank lines). And when your code produces error messages you need to post the full error traceback, don't just give us vague hints. BTW, `asin` is the inverse function to `sin`, so it's rather confusing that you use the name `asin` to refer to `sin`.

Comment: I have considered what you said, I haven't noticed that it refers to the inverse function to sin. So what are your advices to make this calculator scientific ? How should I put the sin?

Answer (score 1):

In your `equal_button_press` function, write:

```
elif self.asin_trigger:
    solution = sin(float(self.calc_value))   # the sine of x is given by sin(x)
```

and then:

```
# remove float() to prevent crashing when the Entry box is empty
print(self.calc_value, " ", self.entry_value.get(), " ", solution)
```